# If $G$ is a finite abelian group, and $\pi : G \to \text{End}(V)$ is an irreducible representation. Show that dim$(V)$ = 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I tried to prove this, but I am not sure about a few things.

Take $v \in V$ and let $W$ be the vector space spanned by $\pi(g)v$ for all $g \in G$.

Firstly, $W \subseteq V$ because for any $w \in W$, there exists $g \in G$ and $v \in V$ such that $w = \pi(g) v$, but $\pi(g) v \in V$ because $\pi(g)$ is an endomorphism.

Secondly, $W$ is $G$-invariant because for any $w \in W$, there exists a group element $h$ such that $w = \pi(h)v$, and if we choose another element $g$ and look at the action of $g$ on $w$, $\pi(g) w $ $= \pi(g) \pi(h) v $ $= \pi(gh) v \in W$.

Theses two properties of $W$ show us that $W$ is a subrepresentation, but $V$ is irreducible, so $V$ and $W$ are equivalent representations because $W$ is nonempty by how we defined it.

Furthermore, I want to apply Schur's lemma, so I define the map $\phi_g: V \to V$ by $\phi_g(v) = \pi(g)v$ for $g \in G$. This map is intertwining, because for any $h \in G$ and $v \in V$,

\begin{align}
\phi_g(\pi(h)v) & = \pi(h)(\phi_g(v)), \\ 
\pi(g)(\pi(h)v) & = \pi(h)(\pi(g)v). 
\end{align}

Then by Schur's lemma we know that $\phi_g = \lambda_g \text{Id}$. Does this mean that $\pi(g) = \lambda_g \text{Id}$? If yes, then can I conclude that the vectors in $V$ are all scalar multiples of each other and therefore dim$(V)$ = 1?

My problem also is that I couple the intertwining map with an element from the group.

Comment: You don't need to define $\phi_g$ separately. Since it is just identically equal to $\pi(g)$, just say: $\pi(g)$ is an intertwining map, because $G$ is abelian. So Schur's lemma applies to it. And yes, that finishes the proof.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you! Are all vectors in V scalar multiples of each other because of the way that W is defined?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Thank you again.